# Equivalence of setTag(key, value) in XML

Tags: android, xml, view

I can use equivalence of `setTag(key)` at my Android layout files as this:

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
         android:tag="key"
         android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

I would like to use equivalence of `setTag(key, value)` at my xml.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party... but anyways you can do this from xml if you are using api level 21 or above. I am not sure whether the memory leak issue is still present or not.

```
<Button
android:layout_width=match_parent
android:layout_height=wrap_content
android:text="New button" >
     <tag android:id="SomeId" android:value="SomeValue" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Is there any option to achieve this in Kitkat?

Comment: Well the official documentation says that it was introduced in API level 4 so this should work from java without any problem. Not sure about the XML approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is this:
`<tag android:id="..." android:value="..."/>`