# <Tag> is not supported in Kitkat version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using `<tag>` for `View` in Android. I tried to add multiple tags for Button.

```
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLOSE" >
            <tag
                android:id="@+id/close_one"
                android:value="@string/close_one_string" />
            <tag
                android:id="@+id/close_two"
                android:value="@string/close_two_string" />
   </Button>
```

I executed my application in Kitkat tablet and Marshmallow tablet. In marshmallow it works fine. But In kitkat it doesn't run.

So, I searched on internet related to this topic. In stackoverflow I found one answer that `<tag>` is supported above API level 21. [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38180527/5898862)

After that I refereed Android documentation where I found, it supports from API level 4. [Click Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag())

My question is how to give support for `<tag>` in Kitkat?

Answer (score 2):

The tag you are referring to in the documentation is when you call it from code. The xml `<tag>` is only avaivable on API 21+

Comment: Is there no option to add multiple tags in xml API level below 21?